# Python: How is the function argument treated inside a decorator?

Tags: python, decorator

I am trying to use decorators and find them kinda cool but I don't completely understand what is going on inside. Let's assume a simple example I borrowed from one of the pages about decorators.

```
def p_decorate(func):
   def func_wrapper(name):
       return "<p>{0}</p>".format(func(name))
   return func_wrapper


def get_text(name):
   return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)


get_text = p_decorate(get_text)
print(get_text("John"))
```

The thing that confuses me in `p_decorate` function is where do we get the `name` argument from? I shall describe how I understand the procedure.

1. We create a `get_text` function with a `name` argument
2. We create decorator function `p_decorate` with a `func` argument that will be our `get_text` function obviously
3. When we call `p_decorate(get_text)`, `func` argument of `p_decorate` becomes our `get_text` function
4. The inner `func_wrapper` function has access to outer scope so it does with `func` (aka `get_text`) whatever it wants. But how does it know about the `name` argument of `get_text`? Moreover, where does it get this argument (since it doesn't complain about the absence of `name`)? We do not provide it to `get_text` after all.
5. ???

Comment: The name of the computer science concept describing the behavior you are seeing here is "closure". Use that word in your searches and you'll find all the information you need. Here's a [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, `name` is going to be the argument passed to your function.  In other cases, where we don't know much about the function, we can use `*args` and `**kwargs` where you have `name` in your decorator.   A pretty concise explanation actually exists [here](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/).